# Regexp - find a value shown after string, (TCL)

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to return a value to `$output`, from `out_buffer`, so i did :

```
set output ""
set out_buffer {Unevictable:           0 kB}
#regexp -line {Unevictable:.* (.*\d).*KB} $out_buffer dummy output
if {!($output == "0")} {
    return 0
} else {
    puts "Unevictable is OK (equal 0)"
}
```

It works fine, but if `out_buffer` is like:

```
set out_buffer {cat /proc/meminfo | grep Unevictable
Unevictable:           0 kB
root@ltqcpe:/ramdisk/tmp# }
```

the return is null. What can I do ? that in any combination the value after `Unevictable:` will be put into `$output`.

Comment: Check your code please. Both give no matches because `KB` in the regex doesn't match `kB` and if you change the regex, for that, both match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the `-line` option to `regexp` so that `^` and `$` are line-aware. (Maybe the `-nocase` option too.) Then you can do this (which I've tested with both your sample input strings):

```
regexp -line -nocase {^Unevictable:\s*(\d+)\s*kB$} $out_buffer -> size
```

Also remember to check the result of `regexp`; it's the number of times the RE matched, which is `0` or `1` (conveniently boolean!) unless you also pass in the `-all` option.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to write regular expressions to match your string. Try something like

```
if {regexp {Unevictable:\s+(\d+)\s+kB} $out_buffer ignore size } {
    puts "size = $size"
}
```